# SQL Function Return Appropriate Length String

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Below is a function that pads an input string to desired length on the specified side of the input string. When executed by SSIS the meta data is not returning the desired length. I need it to return the appropriate data length to SSIS.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_FillField] 
(
    @StringOrg nvarchar(max), --Original string
    @LengthOfStringOutPut int, --Length of output sting
    @FillChr nvarchar(1), --Char to pad the original string
    @LRJustified nvarchar(1) --Left or right justified
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    --  Declare Variable(s)
    DECLARE @Result nvarchar(max)

    --  Left Justified
    IF @LRJustified = 'L'
        BEGIN 
            SET @Result = 
                LEFT(ISNULL(@StringOrg, ''), @LengthOfStringOutPut) + 
                REPLICATE(@FillChr, (@LengthOfStringOutPut - LEN(LEFT(ISNULL(@StringOrg, ''), @LengthOfStringOutPut))))
        END 
    --  Right Justified
    IF @LRJustified = 'R'
        BEGIN
            SET @Result = 
                REPLICATE(@FillChr, (@LengthOfStringOutPut - LEN(LEFT(ISNULL(@StringOrg, ''), @LengthOfStringOutPut)))) + 
                LEFT(ISNULL(@StringOrg, ''), @LengthOfStringOutPut) 
        END
    --  Incorrect Parameter Input
    IF @LRJustified <> 'R' AND @LRJustified <> 'L'
        BEGIN
            SET @Result = 
                NULL
        END

    --  Output Data
    RETURN @Result
END
```

Comment: It's returning `nvarchar(max)` Is SSIS not picking up that length?

Comment: That's the problem I am having. I need it to pickup the length of the actual output. If returning a string of length 30 I need SSIS to pickup on the length of 30. This function is used in a query that produces a very large file. Each column has a specific length as it is a fixed width file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UDF is defined as returning `nvarchar(max)`. SSIS is going to look at the metadata for the function, see that it specifies that it returns `nvarchar(max)`, or DT_NTEXT as SSIS will classify it, and it's done with validation.

The only way you're going to be able to use your function is explicitly cast the results to the appropriate size.

```
SELECT
    CAST(dbo.udf_FillField(T.col1, 100, N'X', N'R') AS nvarchar(100)) AS Col1
FROM
    dbo.MyTable AS T;
```

As a side note, UDFs feel like code reuse, that's what we're taught as developers. But in SQL Server, they are an abomination because the Optimizer has no way of producing an accurate cost for how much work the function will require so it guesses, and 100 times out of 100, it's probably wrong. You will get a consistent implementation of whatever business logic you're encapsulating but the penalty to performance can be severe based on data volumes and logic required.

Comment: I was afraid that this was the case. Thanks for your reply.